# Add local markdown files to GraphQL layer in Gridsome

Tags: gridsome

In Gridsome, how do you add local markdown files to the GraphQL layer, so that you can [add graphql to vue components](https://gridsome.org/docs/components#add-graphql-to-components)?

At the time of writing, the Gridsome docs for [adding data from local files](https://gridsome.org/docs/fetching-data#add-data-from-local-files) are empty.

Answer (score 1):

The starter-blog also has a working implementation: https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome-starter-blog/blob/master/gridsome.config.js

The gridsome repo for `source-filesystem` has some docs to help: https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/tree/master/packages/source-filesystem

Docs imported here in case the link breaks in the future (but the link is likely to be more up to date).

## @gridsome/source-filesystem

> Transform files into content that can be fetched with GraphQL in your components.

### Install

- `yarn add @gridsome/source-filesystem`
- `npm install @gridsome/source-filesystem`

### Usage

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      use: '@gridsome/source-filesystem',
      options: {
        path: 'blog/**/*.md',
        typeName: 'BlogPost',
        route: '/blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

A filesystem source will also require a transformer in order to parse the files. The example above is looking for a set of [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) files, so in order to let [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org) understand the content of the files, you must install [@gridsome/transformer-remark](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gridsome/transformer-remark) as a dev dependency in your project. Gridsome will automatically transform the files for you as long as a transformer that supports your files is found in your `package.json`.

### Options

path

- Type: `string` *required*

Where to look for files. Should be a glob path.

typeName

- Type: `string`
- Default: `'FileNode'`

The GraphQL type and template name. A `.vue` file in `src/templates` must match the `typeName` to have a template for it.

route

- Type: `string`

Define a dynamic route if your source is able to have a certain pathname structure. This will generate a single route for all nodes from this source. Possible path params are `year`, `month`, `day`, `slug` or any custom field value. If omitted, a route for each file will be generated based on their path and filename. Read more about [route params](https://gridsome.org/docs/routing#route-params).

refs

- Type: `object`

Define fields that will have a reference to another node. The referenced `typeName` is expected to exist. But a content type can also be created autmatically if you set `create: true`. Read more about [references](https://gridsome.org/docs/data-store-api#collectionaddreferencefieldname-typename).

```js
{
  refs: {
    // Reference to existing authors by id.
    author: 'Author',
    // Create a Tag content type and its nodes automatically.
    tags: {
      typeName: 'Tag',
      route: '/tag/:id',
      create: true
    }
  }
}
```

index

- Type: `Array`
- Default: `['index']`

Define which files to consider as index files. These files will not have their filename appear in its route path and will become the main `index.html` file of the directory. Make sure there is only one possible index file per directory if multiple index names are defined.